# Ошибка Could not find a method при назначении слушателя нажатий в xml

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Есть android приложение, необходимо сделать выбор времени(установить время), делаю это при помощи TimePickerDialog-а, т.е. пользователь жмет конпку и появляется диалоговое окно, вот и кнопка:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_start"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/time_to_start_hint"
        android:onClick="showTimePicker"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:focusable="false"/>
```

А вот метод, который вызывается ей:

```
    public void showTimePicker(View v)
{
    int hour = 8;
    int minute = 0;
    String st, temp[];
    if(v == mStartDay) {
        st = mStartDay.getText().toString();
        if(st != null && !st.equals(""))
        {
            temp = st.split(":");
            hour = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            minute = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        }
        else {
            hour = 8;
            minute = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        st = mStopDay.getText().toString();
        if(st != null && !st.equals(""))
        {
            temp = st.split(":");
            hour = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            minute = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        }
        else {
            hour = 17;
            minute = 0;
        }
    }
    final EditText timeText = (EditText)v;
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
            SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
            timeText.setText(sfd.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.select_time));
    mTimePicker.show();
}
```

а вот что получаю:

```
02-11 20:47:23.265 9098-9098/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.fitnesseyescommand.fitnesseyes, PID: 9098
                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showTimePicker(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'et_stop'
                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3843)
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4471)
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18778)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showTimePicker [class android.view.View]
                                                 at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
                                                 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:864)
                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3836)
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4471) 
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18778) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                 atdalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

02-11 20:47:33.839 9196-9247/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x65d728d0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x643f28c0 arg=0x0
02-11 20:47:33.839 9196-9247/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x65d728d0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
02-11 20:47:33.847 9196-9246/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x665a81a8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x642d48c0 arg=0x0
02-11 20:47:33.847 9196-9246/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x665a81a8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
02-11 20:47:56.639 148-626/? E/AudioMTKHardware: setCommonParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=off"
02-11 20:48:01.128 741-741/? E/KeyguardHostView: KeyguardHostView()
02-11 20:48:01.776 953-953/? E/HwLauncher: Launcher dialog dismiss failed : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 1 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog
02-11 20:48:29.244 9371-9371/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-11 20:48:29.442 9371-9371/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-11 20:48:29.442 9371-9371/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка? Раньше все работало. Обновил IDE, SDK и теперь проблемы.

Comment: Никогда не назначайте слушатели нажатий на вьюхи в `xml`. От этого много проблем и неясностей. Перенесите назначение слушателя в код

Comment: спасибо, так и сделал, заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое решение проблемы - это назначить `OnClickListener` в методе `onCreate`, в другом случае может быть проблема в тому, что в XML коде назначен не тот `Context` "контроллер", ну или в самом коде не та `XML` страница подключается.

Еще можешь зажать `Ctrl` и кликнуть по методу в `XML`, увидишь куда приведет(но не всегда работает).

Так же можешь снова пересоздать `Activity`, с готовых (ПКМ-New-Activity-Empty) и копипастишь код, но сохрани заголовок с настройками.